# GAE - Queries and Indexes inquiry

Tags: java, google-app-engine

at this link
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html

i found that you can return query result with an easy way and add
filter and so on

and to get the result list  :
List results =
datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());

**my question is here :**
i have java bean class called Offer

how to cast result to be list not list
how can i do this step ??

Comment: the question is very unclear, could you elaborate what you are trying to do and what you are trying to ask?